# Parse XML or JSON in PL/SQL

Tags: xml, json, google-maps, plsql, oracle-apex

I want to parse the output of google maps geocode (specifically the longitude and latitude) which is returned. This can be returned in XML or JSON (I do not really have a preference, I just need the information). I am using utl_httprequest to get the JSON or XML from google and then that gets stored in a variable, but I have no idea how to extract the info. I read http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a96621/adx20ppl.htm but it did not really help.

The google geocode is formatted as such https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#GeocodingRequests

Answer (score 1):

If you want to parse json you might want check out my framework: https://github.com/doberkofler/PLSQL-JSON

Answer (score 0):

I found this website which explains how to parse very well. http://www.mercatorgeosystems.com/blog-articles/2008/06/02/extracting-xml-information-using-pl/sql/

It utilizes the 'extract' method and the stringtovalue method

Answer (score 0):

when I parse xml file I sow that Oracle XML parse to slow, so I parse with using INSTR and SUBSTR. It's not so flexible, but it's fastest way except maybe parsing in java package or C procedure